# Saving climatology result to netcdf file

Tags: python, io, netcdf

I wanted to save a climatological file so that every time I need to calculate anomaly, I don't have to run the climatology script (and it takes a lot of time!) again.
The files are apparently in this manner "CODEYYYYMMTTTT":

```
hgap1981040000.nc
hgap1981040600.nc
hgap1981041200.nc
hgap1981041800.nc
```

I tried to save the climatology average (calculated from netcdf) to a netcdf file using the script below, and I got error.

```
from pylab import *
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np

u_2a=[]
v_2a=[]
w_2a=[]
u_2m=[]
v_2m=[]
w_2m=[]

#function to calculate mean values (this case, Apr-May only)    
def mon(mo):
    for yr in range (1981,1984,1):
        dir_erai = '~/era-in/netc/monthly_means/{}/hgap{}{}????.nc'.format(yr,yr,mo)
        print yr
        f = nc.MFDataset(dir_erai)
        uwnd = f.variables['U']
        vwnd = f.variables['V']
        wwnd = f.variables['W']
        u_2 = np.mean(uwnd[0:4,:,:,:],axis=0)
        v_2 = np.mean(vwnd[0:4,:,:,:],axis=0) 
        w_2 = np.mean(vwnd[0:4,:,:,:],axis=0)
        f.close()   
        u_2a.append(u_2)
        v_2a.append(v_2)
        w_2a.append(w_2)
    u_2m=np.mean(u_2a,axis=0)
    v_2m=np.mean(v_2a,axis=0)
    w_2m=np.mean(w_2a,axis=0)

    return u_2m,v_2m,w_2m


uapr,vapr,wapr = mon('04')
umay,vmay,wmay = mon('05')

uAM = np.mean([uapr,umay],axis=0)
vAM = np.mean([vapr,vmay],axis=0)
wAM = np.mean([wapr,wmay],axis=0)

root_grp = Dataset('climatology_test.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
root_grp.description = 'Example climatology winds UVW'
# dimensions
root_grp.createDimension('time', None)
root_grp.createDimension('lev', 37)
root_grp.createDimension('lat', 256)
root_grp.createDimension('lon', 512)
# variables
times = root_grp.createVariable('time', 'f8', ('time',))
levels = root_grp.createVariable('level', 'f4', ('lev',))
latitudes = root_grp.createVariable('latitude', 'f4', ('lat',))
longitudes = root_grp.createVariable('longitude', 'f4', ('lon',))
U1 = root_grp.createVariable('U1', 'f4', ('time', 'lev', 'lat', 'lon',))
V1 = root_grp.createVariable('V1', 'f4', ('time', 'lev', 'lat', 'lon',))
W1 = root_grp.createVariable('W1', 'f4', ('time', 'lev', 'lat', 'lon',))

# data
levs = [1000.,975.,950.,925.,900.,875.,850.,825.,800.,775.,750.,700.,650.,600.,550.,500.,450.,400.,350.,300.,250.,200.,175.,150.,125.,100.,70.,50.,30.,20.,10.,7.,5.,3.,2.,1.,0] 
lats =  np.arange(-89.5, 89.5, 0.70)
lons =  np.arange(0., 358.4, 0.70)
levels[:] = levs
latitudes[:] = lats
longitudes[:] = lons
uAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
vAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
wAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))

root_grp.close()
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "era_uv_climatology.py", line 99, in <module>
    uAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
IndexError: too many indices
```

i did change

```
uAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
vAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
wAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
```

to

```
U1 = uAM
V1 = vAM
W1 = wAM
```

and I got a wrong and empty netCDF file with all winds values equal to zero, and wrong lon-lat range (1,2,3,...,256), and (1,2,3....,512) .

Is the averaging method or assigning values wrong? or both?

Comment: Are the dimensions to `uwnd` levels x time x lat x lon?  If so, what is the size of `time`?  It appears you're reading in a monthly-mean...is it just a size of 1?

Comment: The file's dimension is [time, level, lat, lon]. The example of files are added above (edited version of this question). The monthly mean is averaged in a manner of 6 hourly. Something like : the mean of April 1998 at 0000, 0600, 1200, and 1800.

Comment: I recommend looking at [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org) for this kind of manipulations.

Answer (score 3):

This first piece of code,

```
    uAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
    vAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
    wAM[:,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
```

is giving you that error because the shape of your random uniform is not the same has the netcdf variables. Try instead.

```
    uAM[0,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
    vAM[0,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
    wAM[0,:,:,:] = np.random.uniform(size=(len(levs), len(lats), len(lons)))
```

And are your closing the climatology file with the close method at the end?

Comment: I forgot about the close method. However, it's still not working even when I did.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the lack of a `close()` call, nowhere are you writing values into your variables. To do so:

```
U1[:] = uAM
V1[:] = vAM
W1[:] = wAM
```

When you set one variable equal to another in Python, like:

```
U1 = uAM
```

You're only changing what the name `U1` refers (points) to--you're not actually changing anything about the object that **was** pointed to by `U1`. So in the case of your script, you reset `U1` to point to the array of data, and you lose the reference to the NetCDF variable you created.

Comment: I just edit (and tested) with "close()" added. No luck.

Comment: As well as the suggested method. No luck. I did a few other option as well,either empty file or error (too many indices) was returned.

Comment: `uAM` is multi-dimensional, you still need to include the correct number of brackets in the assignment.  `U1[:,:,:] = uAM`

Comment: upvote for mentioning the dimension and assigning variable. I added the adjusted code in an answer when I got a better result. There are some errors in the output file, such as, the lon and lat values are in this manner: [1,2,3,....] instead of [-89.5,...,89.5] . The same with longitude. There is a plot, but it's upside down.

Comment: The upside down plot could be a function of how you're plotting. If you're using matplotlib's `imshow()`, for example, you need to specify whether the origin is the lower or upper left corner, using the `origin` kwarg.

Answer (score 1):

After some suggestions and starting over the coding, I managed to get the desired result by using script below. Although, how to get the *lon* and *lat* values stick to *0 to 360* and *90 to -90*, respectively, is still a mystery.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
from netCDF4 import *
import numpy as np
import time
from numpy.random import uniform

u_2a=[]
v_2a=[]
w_2a=[]
u_2m=[]
v_2m=[]
w_2m=[]

def mon(mo):
    for yr in range (1981,2011,1):
        dir_erai = '~/netc/monthly_means/{}/hgap{}{}????.nc'.format(yr,yr,mo)
        print yr
        f = nc.MFDataset(dir_erai)
        uwnd = f.variables['U']
        vwnd = f.variables['V']
        wwnd = f.variables['W']
        u_2 = np.mean(uwnd[0:4,:,:,:],axis=0)
        v_2 = np.mean(vwnd[0:4,:,:,:],axis=0) 
        w_2 = np.mean(vwnd[0:4,:,:,:],axis=0)
        f.close()   
        u_2a.append(u_2)
        v_2a.append(v_2)
        w_2a.append(w_2)
    u_2m=np.mean(u_2a,axis=0)
    v_2m=np.mean(v_2a,axis=0)
    w_2m=np.mean(w_2a,axis=0)

    return u_2m,v_2m,w_2m


uapr,vapr,wapr = mon('04')
umay,vmay,wmay = mon('05')
usep,vsep,wsep = mon('09')
uoct,voct,woct = mon('10')

#creating netcdf
rootgrp = Dataset('climatology_u.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
print rootgrp.data_model

level = rootgrp.createDimension('level',None)
lat = rootgrp.createDimension('lat', 256)
lon = rootgrp.createDimension('lon', 512)
print rootgrp.dimensions

levels = rootgrp.createVariable('level','i4',('level',))
latitudes = rootgrp.createVariable('latitude','f4',('lat',))
longitudes = rootgrp.createVariable('longitude','f4',('lon',))
U1 = rootgrp.createVariable('U1','f4',('level','lat','lon',))
V1 = rootgrp.createVariable('V1','f4',('level','lat','lon',))
W1 = rootgrp.createVariable('W1','f4',('level','lat','lon',))


rootgrp.description = 'Create UVW climatology'
rootgrp.source = 'netCDF4 python module tutorial'
latitudes.units = 'degrees north'
longitudes.units = 'degrees east'
levels.units = 'hPa'
U1.units = 'm/s'
V1.units = 'm/s'
W1.units = 'm/s'

lats =  np.arange(-89.5, 89.5, 0.70)
lons =  np.arange(0., 358.4, 0.70)
latitudes[:]=lats[::-1] #this probably doesn't matter
longitudes[:]=lons


nlats = len(rootgrp.dimensions['lat'])
nlons = len(rootgrp.dimensions['lon'])
print 'U1 shape before adding data = ',U1.shape
U1[0:37,:,:] = uniform(size=(37,nlats,nlons))
V1[0:37,:,:] = uniform(size=(37,nlats,nlons))
W1[0:37,:,:] = uniform(size=(37,nlats,nlons))
print 'U1 shape after adding data = ',U1.shape
levels[:] = [1000.,975.,950.,925.,900.,875.,850.,825.,800.,775.,750.,700.,650.,600.,550.,500.,450.,400.,350.,300.,250.,200.,175.,150.,125.,100.,70.,50.,30.,20.,10.,7.,5.,3.,2.,1.,0] 

U1[:,:,:]=uapr[:,::-1,:] # without "::-1", the data is upside down,sth to do with source dataset
V1[:,:,:]=vapr[:,::-1,:]
W1[:,:,:]=wapr[:,::-1,:]


rootgrp.close()
```

Comment: geez! turn out the result is different from the one I did manually (comparison from the one climatology file produced above, with the one I did manually in python).